How to adjust pictures alignment on fpdf
I have this code that generates a investment summary and some analytic images
def investment_summary(pdf, text, bullet_indent=15):
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=8)

    for point in text.splitlines():
        if point.startswith("-"):
            pdf.set_x(bullet_indent)
        pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, point)

def add_analytics(pdf, image_paths):
  for image in image_paths:
    pdf.image(image, w=180, h=100)  # Adjust width (w) and height (h) as needed
    pdf.add_page()  # Start a new page for each graph

def create_report(county_and_state, llm_text, analytics_location_path=None):
    
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    
    pdf.set_text_color(r=50,g=108,b=175)
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 18)
    
    
    pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt="Verus-AI: " + county_and_state, ln=1,align='C')
    
    
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt="Investment Summary", ln=1,align='L')
    
    investment_summary(pdf, llm_text)

    pdf.set_text_color(r=50,g=108,b=175)
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt="Analytics", ln=1,align='L')
    add_analytics(pdf, analytics_location_path)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    pdf.output(f'./example1.pdf', 'F')

The issue is the add_analytics function makes new pages for each image. I would like these images to use as much of the space as possible while still being nice to see from the users perspective.
This is what the output looks like

I changed my code to add this function
def add_analytics1(pdf, image_paths):
    size_of_image = 150
    for image in image_paths:
        pdf.image(image, w=size_of_image, x=((pdf.w-size_of_image)/2))
        pdf.ln(h=2.5)

but now I am getting this

How do I make sure the first picture does not slightly shift to the left?

you add a new page each time you add an image , why you do that ? : also can you provide to use a code that we can try , because these are functions we need a code we can try it and edit it.

Can you edit this part ? : pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt="Analytics", ln=1,align='L') to be : pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt="Analytics", ln=1,align='C')

That just adjusted the title of the section, the graphs still have that odd spacing that is happening.

Can you provide your code that you use , not only the functions,  add the input please.

@Mohammedalmalki What is the best way to share the input? I have pictures and text

can you delete it, then install it : pip install fpdf2

@Mohammedalmalki I tried, but still having the same issue

you can add an image and also center that image, and also add a space after each image, using this code :
I was using this library:

pip install fpdf2


from fpdf import FPDF

size_of_image = 150


pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_margin(5.0)



pdf.image("ex.png", w=size_of_image, x=((pdf.w-size_of_image)/2))
pdf.ln(h=2.5)

pdf.image("ex.png", w=size_of_image, x=((pdf.w-size_of_image)/2))
pdf.ln(h=2.5)

pdf.image("ex.png", w=size_of_image, x=((pdf.w-size_of_image)/2))
pdf.ln(h=2.5)


pdf.output('final.pdf')


in this code we specify the width only, to be clear,
because if you added the width and the height, then in that time you are forcing your image to fit that space even if it is smaller or bigger,
this will reduce the quality,
in my code, I added the width only, for that the height will be specified auto by the library depending on the height of the image.
and this will lead to adding a clear image.
and this is the result :

The new problem is :
that you are using an old version of FPDF :
this is what i got when i had run your code :

it says that your code has a lot that have been changed and removed from the new version , and are available in the old version that you use.
just update your version.

I get an attribute error message about set_margin() what version are you using?

Your code works when I remove the set_margin part, the only problem is the first image will be centered but then when it proceeds to the next page the first image will be slightly shifted to the left while the other two images below will be centered, any idea whats going on?

you have to use the latest version or FPDF, it is more stable and better.

pip install fpdf2

everything is working fine with me, i do not know what do you mean by "when it proceeds to the next page the first image will be slightly shifted to the left while the other two images below will be centered"

@wolfy or show me the problem to solve it.

Just edited my post

Should I uninstall fpdf then install fpdf2?

I am using fpdf2==2.7.9, but I still get AttributeError: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'set_margin'

I will reward with the points but could you help me fix the issue?

@wolfy of course I can help you,  can you please tell me what is your python version ?

@wolfy to be honest with you , I am sure that the problem is in the version that you use , I will try to create a project contains the FPDF that I use and upload it on github , then you can try it , and tell me what will happen.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
